# Nav Bar Element Not Active? (links arent working)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a sidebar with links on a wordpress page.

Screenshot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiGXb.jpg

HTML for sidebar:

```
    <div class="right">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.right{ position: absolute; top: 400px; right:980px; bottom: 80px;}
```

Basically it just doesn't treat the links as links. It's like the element is disabled. All I can do is see the element. I think it's behind something...not sure. I've played around with th eposition and I can get it to work if I make it relative but then it messes up the location of the sidebar.

Also: I know there are more effective ways of doing this, but I am a student with restricted access to the admin panel of this wordpress site so I'm just trying to do what I can with what I can.

Thank you for any advice/wisdom!

UPDATE: Works in IE just not Chrome...wtf

Answer (score 0):

> "I think it's behind something...not sure"

Try to add `z-index: 1000;` (or higher) and `width: 400px;`.
`z-index` will move the absolute element on top of other elements. Sort of like layers.

**Example**

```
.right {
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. That didn't seem to work :( but I tried it in IE and it works...just doens't work in Chrome hmmmm

Comment: Got it working! I needed to set a width. Thanks for your time everyone!